# Why isn't my CSS parallax working?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to follow the [Keith Clark tutorial](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) for parallax images, but I can't seem to get it working correctly.

I'm using the skeleton CSS framework, and am simply trying to recreate an existing website to get some experience with HTML and CSS.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg98sj29/5/)

```css
#ingredients {
    postion: float;
    padding: 5rem 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 600px;
}
    
#ingredients h1{
    margin-top: 20rem;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
    
.parallax {
    height: 100rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-perspective: 1px;
    perspective: 1px;
}
    
.parallax__layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 100vh 0;
}
    
.parallax__layer--base {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
    
.parallax__layer--back {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px);
    transform: translateZ(-1px);
}
    
    
.title{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="ingredients"><!--
 --><div class="parallax">
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
            <div class="title">
            The background
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>The <strong>Freshest</strong> Seasonal Ingredients</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Scroll all the way down on the HTML, CSS, and Result section and you will find my attempted parallax section in the #ingredients. Right now my issue is that there are two scrollbars in this section. If I get rid of the extra scrollbar, the parallax no longer works.

Comment: One big, two-fold issue I see with your CSS is that `position: float;` is not a valid property-value pair. `float` is it's own property, not a value of `position`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the horizontal scroll bar. You can add :

```
body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

At the beginning of your CSS. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/Lg98sj29/6/)